# How do you send logging to Google Stackdriver with Rails/Lograge?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

We have a project that's configured with both Rails/Lograge.  According to the documentation it seems that you simply include the gem.  I'm wondering if it's possible to send additional information as a jsonPayload.  All of our logging is being parsed only as textPayload.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/stackdriver

https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/v2/rest/v2/LogEntry

We're also using AppEngine Flex so we have less control over the Fluentd implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the use of Ruby with Stackdriver logging is pretty well documented.  See for example [Stackdriver Logging Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-ruby).

Next we find reference documentation on the APIs here [Module: Google::Cloud::Logging](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/docs/google-cloud-logging/latest/Google/Cloud/Logging).  And if we look at the `Logger` class, we find an example of writing a JSON payload to the log:

https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-ruby/docs/google-cloud-logging/latest/Google/Cloud/Logging/Logger.html

```rb
require "google/cloud/logging"

logging = Google::Cloud::Logging.new

resource = logging.resource "gae_app",
                            module_id: "1",
                            version_id: "20150925t173233"

logger = logging.logger "my_app_log", resource, env: :production

payload = { "stats" => { "a" => 8, "b" => 12.5} }
logger.info payload
```

Comment: Is it possible to additionally send `HttpRequest` payload?  Looks like you don't access to the LogEntry entity

Comment: Nvm I see.  Thanks!